# how to change text tab into html tab in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

how to change text tab into html tab in wordpress? wordpress is not my strongest point, so if anyone has an idea about what might be going wrong I would appreciate some insight.

[image]

Comment: sorry but not getting what you want and what is the significance of placing the WP text editor image..let me know the case

Comment: This editor has not generated the proper html tags when i hit a text tab @swapnesh

Comment: Editor visual problem also @swapnesh

Answer (score 0):

use `<code> </code>` tags

Comment: in the text editor. put your html inside those tags. also have a look at this http://tutorialblog.org/use-embedit-to-add-html-code-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Find `class-wp-editor.php` in your `wp-include` directory. I think that's where you can start from.